# Why multithreading pyFFTW is slower?

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, fft, fftw, pyfftw

Recently, I need to conduct the parallel FFT on images which is just the two dimensional matrix, and I used pyFFTW in my python programs.However, the result shows that multithreading pyFFTW is slower, and I don't known where the problem is. The followings are my testing code:

```
def pyfftw64(inp):
    u0 = pyfftw.empty_aligned(inp.shape, dtype='float64')
    u1 = pyfftw.empty_aligned((inp.shape[0], inp.shape[-1]//2 + 1), dtype='complex128')
    
    fft_plan = pyfftw.FFTW(u0, u1, axes=(-2,-1), direction='FFTW_FORWARD', flags=('FFTW_MEASURE',), threads=4)
    ifft_plan = pyfftw.FFTW(u1, u0, axes=(-2,-1), direction='FFTW_BACKWARD', flags=('FFTW_MEASURE',), threads=4)
    
    u0[:] = inp

    start = time.time()
    for i in range(0,1000):
        fft_plan()
        ifft_plan()
    
    #fft_plan()
    #ifft_plan()

    end = time.time()
    
    return end-start
```

I have tried different matrix size and the threads argumnet, but there is no apparent accelerating effect. So, I want to ask for your help to give some adivces and the method to check the problem.

Comment: The computing environment is ubuntu in VMWare

Comment: I get a 2.5 speed up on my 10 core Xeon with 4 threads VS 1 thread (on a 1024x1024 array). Maybe the VM is not properly configured or decrease parallel performance.

Comment: @Jérôme Richard Thanks for your comment, and I want to know your speed up on other  matrix sizes, and do you check if the four threads occupy four independent cores respectively?

Comment: The speed ups for 4 threads are 256²:1.0x, 512²:1.2x, 1024²:2.6x, 2048²:3.0x. Note that for 512² arrays, each FFT run takes about 0.6 ms which is pretty small for multiple threads to be efficient even though I expect a better speed up. For 256², the overhead of creating/joining threads and running CPython functions starts to be significant compared to the execution time (of 0.17 ms/run). My guess is that the overheads do not comes from the FFTW but the Python binding. Regarding threads, >=4 cores are generally used (not at 100%). The binding is not guaranteed by the OS by default.

Comment: @Jérôme Richard My tests (10000 times fft and ifft)for 256^2 : 2.4s, 3.7s, 3.8s and 4.9s with 1, 2, 4 and 8 threads respectively; 512^2: 11.6s, 10.8s, 8.6s and 8.2s with responding threads as above. And can I ask for that “”Python binding“” means what?

Comment: By "Python binding" I mean `pyfftw`. Indeed, `pyfftw` show wrap the C calls and it might do some checks with expensive overheads. AFAIR, the FFTW was scaling pretty well using a C code even on a 256² input (I tested it >5 years ago though). I advise you to test a quick example in C (I think the FFTW documentation should provide some example so it should not be too difficult). Alternatively, you can try another library wrapping the FFTW if any. Finally, you can also try to track where the overhead is using profilers and possibly open a bug on `pyfftw` if the overhead is not in the FFTW.

Comment: @Jérôme Richard Thanks for your answer!  As what you say, I also test the C FFTW, and the speed is really faster than the python wrapper, but my base program is Python language, so I have to use the python package FFT. What's more, I also write the python/c module which calls the C FFTW, but it didn't show apparent performance(may be my poor programming level).

Comment: Ok so the C code is fast but not your CPython module calling directly the FFTW? If so, the question is then how the module is written. Did you do any array copy? What method do you use to write a module : the CPython low-level API or any tool like Cython?

Comment: @ Jérôme Richard Yes, I write the python/c fft module using cython referencing the examples given on the net, including the files of .pyc(cython), .c(c++) and .py(python file to setup), ultimately getting the .so file(can be import in actual program).

Comment: Ok. AFAIK the overhead of Cython should be relatively small (which may not be so small if the number of C call from CPython is big). Did you enabled optimizations? Maybe there is an issue with the GIL. You could try to disable it.  Alternatively you could try to write a module with the low-level Python API. It is hard to say what is wrong with the provided information. Profiling is the key to understand what actually happens.