# Why the speeds of multithreading pyfftw on window and linux are different?

Tags: linux, multithreading, parallel-processing, fft, pyfftw

The "threads" argument of pyfftw can induce multithreading parallel computing of FFT on the 2D matrix, and I tested the speeds of pyfftw with different parallel threads on 256*256 matrix, multithreading pyfftw is slower than the single-thread one on ubuntu of VMWare, and is faster than single-thread one on windows.

I don't know where the problem is.

Comment: I think there’s a typo. You are running Ubuntu on VMWare? How did you configure it? Does the virtual machine have access to the full CPU? AFAIK? VMWare also doesn’t give access to the GPU, not sure if you’re using that.  If you want to test timing across platforms, I would suggest you dual-boot your machine, use a true Ubuntu installation.

Comment: @ Cris Luengo Thank you for your answer, I also doubt if the performance of pyfftw is affected by the VM for its inadequate access to the computing resources, and I remember that the same result as the ubuntu's occured on the cluster with centos some time ago, and I can try again later. As for the dual-boot, do you mean the dual systems installed in my PC?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-booting

Comment: It would be good to see the code you used to time the computation.

Comment: @Cris Luengo This is my code used to test:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76627024/why-multithreading-pyfftw-is-slower?noredirect=1#comment135165017_76627024

Comment: You’ve got quite a few questions asking the same thing in slightly different ways. The FFT takes longer when multithreading is the same thing as the cores having low usage. I think this is all related to VMWare. It is probably not configured right. Please install Ubuntu directly, on a separate partition, and boot from that partition (see the dual-boot link I shared earlier). There’s also the possibility that pyfftw is more efficient under Windows than under Linux, but other than wrong compiler choices, I don’t see that happening.

Comment: @Cris Luengo Yes, my questions earlier are all from recent tests of relative FFT modules, including C FFTW and pyFFTW. I also think about whether the problem comes from VMware but I'm not sure.  And can I ask you another question that which FFT package/module is fastest currently? Still FFTW?

Comment: There are many good implementations of the FFT. FFTW still seems to be the go-to library. I've seen some that *claimed* to be faster, but I haven't looked into them very deeply. It's not going to be a significant difference anyway. There are also some implementations that are almost as fast, and a lot simpler. The one used by SciPy and NumPy nowadays (they both switched fairly recently) is one of those (it's called PocketFFT). On my M1 Mac it's actually a bit faster in some cases, but FFTW is not optimized for the M1 chip.

Comment: This benchmark might be useful: https://github.com/project-gemmi/benchmarking-fft/

Comment: @Cris Luengo Thanks a lot for your benchmark link, I go to have a look.